# Creating empty space when merging multiple GEOTIFF files?

Tags: gdal, gdal-merge

I have multiple GEOTIFF files containing information regarding atmospheric parameters. Due to a lack of data in certain regions, I've had to do my geospatial processing separately on them.

Now I'd like to merge the files back together. When I use GDAL_merge, it creates an interpolated space between the two regions. I'd like this to remain as empty space. In addition to this, the file grows very large. Two relatively small files become many magnitudes larger.

```
$ gdal_merge.py -o output.tif input_1.tif input_2.tif
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you read http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html? Did you read this

> -a_nodata output_nodata_value: (GDAL >= 1.9.0) Assign a specified nodata value to output bands

Did you try it? Interpolation between the two tiff files feels odd, I had thought that gdal_merge.py is using just nearest neighbor resampling. Show screen captures of even better make input_1.tif and input_2.tif available.

Nodata pixels between the tif files are pixels as well and as uncompressed they take just as much space that any other pixel. Nodata fortunately compresses well, so make gdal_translate to compress the result by adding for example

```
-co compress=deflate
```